Geopandas Swirl like in Scikit-image?
I am wondering if there is a way to transform a geopandas dataframe similar to what Scikit-image does with Swirl?

Edit:
Thanks again, @Timeless and all, my head is swirling. I am making progress, but I am stuck: I used your codesnippet and (no surprise) it all worked fine as expected and as documented above.
However, when I then use my own geodataframes something is off.  With  exactly the same code I am using this gdf where the first geometry gdf.geometry.iloc[[0]].plot() looks as follows 
But when i swirl gdf.geometry.map(swirl_poly).iloc[[0]].plot() its looks like  with an empty item in the geoseries: GEOMETRYCOLLECTION EMPTY
Any idea what am I doing wrong?
Separate question. If I understand correctly the code swirls each geometry. How would I swirl a whole gdf like the one above, which looks like 
Thanks!

Swirl is an operator that acts on an image. As long as your geopandas dataframe is an image then yes, you can do that.

'as long as your Gdf is an image' - what does that mean? It doesnt work on a Gdf and it won't, but I am looking for ways to transform a Gdf in a similar way...

you have an operator that applies a rotation to an image that depends on the distance from the center (closer pixels to the center get rotated more). Now you want to apply such operator to something else. Can you apply it to a dog? No. Can you apply it to the feeling of happiness? No. Can you apply it to an image or something similar to an image where the definition of rotation and distance from center in meaningful? Yes. We don't know what your geopandas dataframe contains, so without more information it's hard to tell.

I get that and thank you. The challenge is that geodataframes contain line strings, polygons etc, defined by points / coordinates. For affine transformations, that's fine (and geopandas has a function for that). But swirl isn't affine, i.e. a swirled polygon will have curved edges and will need a whole different representation on geopandas. I can't do it after converting the Gdf into an image, SVG etc because I will need to apply geopandas transformations after the swirl like simplify and buffer. Sorry for not being clear enough from the beginning.

Now you are giving proper context for your question! You only need now to create a minimal reproducible example of your dataframe and define what kind of transformation you want to apply. Please post any attempts you made you solve the problem and what difficulties you encountered.

discretize: rasterize, or break everything down into short line segments. then you can swirl all the nodes.

take note of your origins, and what point you're swirling about.

I experimented with the rasterio solution and havent made it work (my bad). But I also started to think about a different idea and was wondering if anyone has thoughts about doing the transformations straight shapely by first "densifying" the shapes like densify in arcgis and then transform each shape / polygon by transforming the nodes of polygon for example with a swirl. Does anyone have thoughts on this approach? will keep you updated here...

A possible solution using rasterio :
from rasterio import features

def swirl_poly(poly, **kwargs):
    img = features.rasterize([poly], out_shape=(70, 50))
    swirled = swirl(
        img,
        rotation=0,
        strength=10,
        radius=60,
        **kwargs,
    ).astype("float32")
    return unary_union(
        [
            Polygon(d["coordinates"][0])
            for d, _ in features.shapes(swirled, mask=swirled != 0)
        ]
    )

Plot (see full code) :


wow, this looks great. I'll need time to try to understand,m but it looks exactly like what I need. Thank you so much! @Timless

Ok, first time for me to provide a proper answer on stackoverflow, albeit only an answer to my own question.
I liked @timeless solution with rasterio, but didn't get it to work. I also didn't like the idea of taking a detour via rasterization. I stumbled over the geopandas segmentize function and realized that it can do something similar to rasterio: rasterize the points on the Polygons only (as opposed to the whole figure. So with the code below, I essentially raterized the polygons and then applied the swirl transformation to each point in the now segmentized Polygons. But this could now be really any transformation. The code only works for Polygons, but I don't see a reason why it shouldn't work for other geometries.
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, Point
import geopandas as gpd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from math import sin,cos, pi, sqrt

#parameters for the swirl transformation
swirlCenter = (2, 2)  # center of the swirlcircle. The Swirlcircle is the circle on which the points on the polygons are rotated with the maxSwirlAngle
swirlRadius = 2  # radius of the swirlcircle
maxSwirlAngle = 0.4  # max angle of rotation on the swirlcircle
maxRadiusSwirled = 1  # maximal distance from swirl circle where points on the Polygons are still swirled

def densifyPolygons(row,maxSegmentLength): #segmentize the geometry in ech row
    return row['geometry'].segmentize(maxSegmentLength)

#swirls the Polygon in each geometry. Swirling is done at max angle in radians on the swirlcircle
#at maxSwirlDistance from the swirlcircle the points of a polygon are no longer rotated
# between the swirlcircle and the maxdistance from the circle the points are rotated with  factor between 0 and 1 of the maxSwirlAngle
# in the example the factor of swirlreduction over distance is a sin curve.
def transformPolygons(row):
    def transformCoordinates(n):  # transform an individual coordinate
        distanceFromSwirlRing=abs(sqrt(pow(n[0]-swirlCenter[0],2)+pow(n[1]-swirlCenter[1],2))-swirlRadius)
        if maxRadiusSwirled<distanceFromSwirlRing:
            swirlAngle=0
        else:
            swirlAngle=maxSwirlAngle*(sin((((maxRadiusSwirled-distanceFromSwirlRing)/maxRadiusSwirled)*pi-pi/2))+1)/2
        newTuple=(swirlCenter[0]+(n[0]-swirlCenter[0])*cos(swirlAngle)-(n[1]-swirlCenter[1])*sin(swirlAngle),
                swirlCenter[1]+(n[0]-swirlCenter[0])*sin(swirlAngle)+(n[1]-swirlCenter[1])*cos(swirlAngle))
        return newTuple
    newgeom=Polygon(list(map(transformCoordinates,row['geometry'].boundary.coords)))# go through coodinates
    return newgeom

#### simple geodataframe to test
TestPolygon1=Polygon([Point(1,1),Point(2,2),Point(3,-1),Point(-1,-2),Point(-2,3),Point(1,1)])
TestPolygon2=Polygon([Point(4,4),Point(5,5),Point(6,2),Point(3,3),Point(1,6),Point(4,4)])
d={'col1':['name1','name2'],'geometry':[TestPolygon1,TestPolygon2]}
inputgdf=gpd.GeoDataFrame(d,crs="EPSG:4326")
outputgdf=inputgdf.copy(deep=True)

#densify the outputgdf
outputgdf['geometry']=outputgdf.apply(densifyPolygons,maxSegmentLength=0.1,axis=1)
#apply the transormation to the Polygons in the geodataframe
outputgdf['geometry']=outputgdf.apply(transformPolygons, axis=1)

#create the circles set as swirl parameter for better visualization
circles=[]
circles.append(Point(swirlCenter).buffer(swirlRadius+maxRadiusSwirled))
circles.append(Point(swirlCenter).buffer(swirlRadius))
circles.append(Point(swirlCenter).buffer(swirlRadius-maxRadiusSwirled))

#add the circles to the gdf tobe able to plot them in one go
for circle in circles:
    inputgdf.loc[len(inputgdf.index)] = ['name',circle.exterior]
    outputgdf.loc[len(outputgdf.index)] = ['name', circle.exterior]


inputgdf.plot()
outputgdf.plot()
plt.show()

I am sure there are lots of things to optimize, but I am learning and very happy to have managed to get this to work. I would appreciate any feedback.
Here is a vizualization of what the code does (circles just to better see the transformation parameters



The code doesn't currently work with Polygons with holes.....working on it
